# How can I get parse a public key from Buffer?

Tags: javascript, buffer

solana/web3.js has a function [PublicKey.toBuffer(key)](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#toBuffer). How do I get the public key back from that buffer?

"decode()" only returns the correct key if i use "encode()" to turn it into a buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the correct key by calling `new PublicKey(buffer)`.

The constructor for `PublicKey` takes a number of different types: `number | string | Buffer | Uint8Array | number[]`

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#PublicKeyInitData

```
import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js'

const pubkey = new web3.PublicKey('CoG95Mk72pkbhpZ5b4WiBseX6a5Dv19HfTp6reLzjfyM');

const buffer = pubkey.toBuffer();

const origPubkey = new web3.PublicKey(buffer);
console.log(origPubkey.toBase58());
```